# Server response with (417) status code in Revmob Add Error

Tags: xcode, ads, revmob

my app in using on advertisement in RevMob add and i have a update Revmob sdk in 9.0.4 in Used but Error Continue 
1)Erroe"Server response with (417) status code"
2)Failed with error: Error Domain=Server response with (417) status code. Code=-1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Server response with (417) status code. error -1.)" how to solve this error please replay fast
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your placements are paused, you should turn them into "playing".
You should go to revmob website, monetization tab, select your app and click on the status sign of your placements (Banner, Fullscreen, etc) to change them.